# How do I recursively zip all subfolders in a directory?

Tags: 12.04, command-line

Currently, I have this directory structure:

```
/Downloads
    /Download 1/
    /Download 2/
    /Download 3/
    ...
```

I would like to have this directory structure:

```
/Downloads
    Download 1.zip
    Download 2.zip
    Download 3.zip
    ...
```

Essentially, I want to zip Download 1 into `Download 1.zip` and then remove Download 1.
What would be the fastest/easiest way to achieve this? I'm running Ubuntu 12.04.

The reason I'm asking is because this folder is shared on my local network. When people ask this on my Apache Web Server, I want them to download `Download 1`, so I need it to be a zip file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try with command I have tried in the image , hope thats gonna help you.

[image]

For removing you just can add an extra line that

```
rm -rf $i
```

The total command can be as

```
 for i in ~/sandbox/*; do zip -r "$i".zip "$i"; rm -rf "$i"; done
```

The command which deletes Folders after verifying successful Zip creation.

```
for i in ~/sandbox/*; do zip -r "$i".zip "$i" && rm -rf "$i"; done
```

Thank you @evilsoup for noticing.
hope that helps.

Comment: Very nice one! :)

Comment: is it bash programming ??

Comment: @Sushantp606 yes brother

Comment: It would be better to use `for i in ~/sandbox/*; do zip -r "$i".zip "$i" && rm -rf "$i"; done` -- that way the `rm` will only be executed if the `zip` succeeds, see [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/334994/which-one-is-better-using-or-to-execute-multiple-commands-in-one-line)

Comment: Yes, thanks for all of the help. rajagenupual's first line worked well, but evilsoup's edit is also good to note. Thanks everyone!

Comment: @sameetandpotatoes you are welcome.