# How to execute several commands after each other with one request to the terminal (without using a file)?

Tags: gnome-terminal, command-line

I could (1) prepare a file with typed commands separated by end-line, (2) make it executable, (3) run it from a file-system manager or the terminal.

But this is ridiculous for not repeatable and every-time-other sets of commands.

Can I type those commands to the terminal in one request instead?

I don't know end-line character for the terminal - Ctrl, Shift or Alt with Enter doesn't work.

Comment: On a command line, commands can be separated with a semicolon.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can separate commands with `&&` or `;`.

- `&&` only runs the next command if the previous one exited with status 0 (was successful) :

  ```
  command1 && command2 && command3
  ```
- `;` runs every commands, even if the previous one exits with a non zero status :

  ```
  command1; command2; command3
  ```

You can combine these separators as you wish.

Comment: for `command1 && command2` command2 will only be executed if command1 is successful.

Comment: Nice discussions, relevant/similar posts: http://askubuntu.com/questions/334994/which-one-is-better-using-or-to-execute-multiple-commands-in-one-line http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13077241/execute-combine-multiple-linux-commands-in-one-line

Comment: @souravc : I made an edit, thanks, I learned something.

Comment: if combining `sudo apt upgrade` and `sudo systemctl reboot`, would you need to add 'sudo' twice, or will it 'remember' sudo for the second command?

Answer (score 9):

If you are interested to type each command on its own line in one single request you can use the following method:

- Start your request (first line) with `if :; then` (this mean: if true, then do) and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>; your prompt will change now in `>` and nothing will be executed.
- Type your commands, each one followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- Finish your request with with `fi` (end of the above `if` condition) and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Now all your commands will be executed in the given order.

Example:

```
radu@Radu: ~ $ if :; then
> echo 'something'
> echo 'something else'
> echo 'List current directory contents:'
> ls
> echo 'Change current directory with root directory:'
> cd
> #finish
> fi
something
something else
List current directory contents:
Backups            Desktop           forma3d  Public      Untitled txt.txt~
bin                Documente         Music    Templates   Videos
configuration.php  examples.desktop  passwd~  tmp~
Downloads          file~             Poze     Ubuntu One
Change current directory with root directory:
radu@Radu: / $
```

Comment: `if true; then` may be clearer to read if so desired. `:` may be confused with the `;` at first glance.

Answer (score 4):

First, put a `{` on its own line.
Then, insert your commands.
Then, put a `}` on a new line and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Your commands will be executed.

Example:

```
{
echo list
echo of
echo commands
echo to run at once
}
```

which will print (all at once, with no prompt in between):

```
list
of
commands
to run at once
```

As a side note, `{ .. }` is the Bash command grouping syntax. It's  often useful in conjunction with `&&` or `||` ('and', and 'or' respectively)

Comment: Is that the same that `if :; then` already mentionned ? Or is it slightly different ?

Comment: @MrVaykadji It's the same outcome, but a different method. `if :` runs a test on the null command, which will always return true. `{ .. }` just groups the commands together. I personally find `{ .. }` easier to remember.