# choice of command-line operator and running a bunch of command line commands one after another

Tags: command-line, bash, python

I wrote a simple python script that outputs a bunch of linux commands for a custom image manipulation command-line tool.

As an example, here is what the python script creates:

```
img_dae_create /d /t /19 "file1.jpg" -output "heavy" -t /mnt/img/output/
img_dae_create /d /t /7 "file2.jpg" -output "light" -t /mnt/img/output/
img_dae_create /d /t /8 "file3.jpg" -output "ex" -t /mnt/img/output/
```

Normally, I just copy and paste them to my Ubuntu command line and run one by one. Each command can take from 1 minute to 15+ minutes to execute.

But sometimes, the python script will generate 100s of these, and it is very tedious to copy and paste each one.

So I was wondering what would be the best command line operator to use in this case?

Would `;` be better than `&&` given that:

- The time it takes for each command to run could be between 1 and 15 minutes.
- The outcome of the command does not matter, if it fails, then the command line tool records that in a log file and can be dealt with later.

Thanks!

Comment: if it is only a couple you can put `&&` between the commands. But for 100s of them you might want to look into making a bash script or at least split them up into smaller chunks.

Comment: @totalynotanoob thanks!  So I'd create a bash script, and the copy and paste the commands with an && symbol between them?

Comment: The answer of the following question could be interesting for you: [Why combine commands on a single line in a Bash script?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1182642/566421)

Comment: the `&&` is for typing directly into the terminal. bash scripts have a different structure because they are made for completing multiple commands in a row. you should look up some tutorials to learn the syntax and structure before trying it out.

Comment: @totalynotanoob whether to use `&&` versus separating the commands over multiple lines (or using `;`) is not about command line versus script - it's about the desired logic. See for example [What are the shell's control and redirection operators?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159513/what-are-the-shells-control-and-redirection-operators)

Comment: Think it was closed too fast...

Comment: @steeldriver so i my case, using `command1 ; command2 ; command3;` would be best right?  Because I need for one command to finish before a new one is started.  I also don't care about outcome, like if it fails or not, because that is recorded by the actual command-line utility that I am using

Comment: @bac0n the original question didn't mention choice of operators - it was just "
running a bunch of command line commands one after another". It was edited after closing - you can vote to reopen if you haven't already done so.

Comment: I was thinking he could do something like `cat | while read -r; do /path/to/$REPLY; done` even change the output from the python to JSON and `cat | jq | while ...`  that would give him some control