# Run two commands in case of || or &&

Tags: command-line, bash

I have read [about && and ||](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4510640/command-line-what-is-the-purpose-of) and I'd like to run two commands in the false case.

I have tried `;` but that is [running always](https://askubuntu.com/a/539293/242307). I have tried putting it in curly braces `{ command1; command2 }` but that results in a syntax error.

I want to do something like

```
command && echo "Ok, continuing" || echo "Check internet connection"; exit 1
```

which is only exited if there's no Internet connection.

Comment: This seems like a simple typographical error. A way more interesting question to ask is the differences between `()` and `{}`.

Comment: related http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/187145/68757

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Using parens puts the commands in a subshell which is not always what you want.  Alternatively, use curly braces:

```
command && echo "Ok, continuing" || { echo "Check internet connection"; exit 1; }
```

The trick here is that, unlike parens, the final command in braces must be followed by `;`.

#### Why a semicolon or newline is required

A curly brace is a valid argument to a command.  For example, here is a curly brace as an argument to `echo`:

```
$ echo }
}
```

Consequently, if the shell sees:

```
{ command1; command2 }
```

The shell interprets command1 as having no arguments and command2 as having one argument consisting of the character `}`.  A curly brace `}` is only interpreted as closing  a grouping if it follows a semicolon or newline.  To make the above work:

```
{ command1; command2; }
```

#### Subshells and the difference between `{...}` and `(...)`

Observe that the following sets `x` to 10 but that that setting is forgotten before the `echo` command runs:

```
$ x=0; false || ( echo Hello; x=10 )
Hello
$ echo $x
0
```

With curly braces, by contrast, the setting of `x=10` is remembered:

```
$ x=0; false || { echo Hello; x=10; }
Hello
$ echo $x
10
```

The difference is because variable assignments in a subshell do not survive after the subshell completes.

#### Documentation

From `man bash`:

> (list)
>
> **list is executed in a subshell environment** (see COMMAND EXECUTION
>   ENVIRONMENT below).  Variable assignments and builtin commands  that 
>   affect              the shell's environment do not remain in effect
>   after the command completes.  The return status is the exit status of
>   list.
>
> { list; }
>
> list is simply executed in the current shell environment.  **list must
>   be terminated with a newline or semicolon.**  This is known as a group
>   command.  The return status is the exit status of list.  Note that
>   unlike the metacharacters ( and ), { and } are reserved words and 
>   must  occur where  a reserved word is permitted to be recognized. 
>   Since they do not cause a word break, they must be separated from list
>   by whitespace or another shell metacharacter.
>
> [Emphasis added]