# Two commands at once in Bash

Tags: command-line, bash

I want to add a bash command that does the following:

Currently, I need to run this:

```
$ pdflatex <filename>.tex | open <filename>.pdf
```

Is there any way to convert that into something like

```
$ complatex <filename>
```

and have both commands executed?

Comment: is `{}` a syntax in `find` command?

Comment: I'm skeptical about your premise since (a) `pdflatex` doesn't usually write to stdout (b) at least on Linux systems `open` doesn't usually open files and (c) even if it did, there would be no reason to pipe to its stdin; I'd expect something more like `pdflatex somefile.tex ; xdg-open somefile.pdf`

Comment: The question is not totally clear, but I think you're looking for this: https://askubuntu.com/a/539293/301745

Comment: I suggest to use a function. See `help function`.

Comment: Thank you for your responses! To address your concerns: 

- I used {} as a placeholder for a name. Nothing fancy.
- `pdflatex` doesn't write to stdout, but it will compile the pdf into the directory, so then, right after I compile it, I want to grab that compiled pdf and display it on my computer. 
- `open` opens files in macos. The actual system I use to open a file is outside the premise of this question, so don't worry about that :)
- To answer the other question, `user$ pdflatex main.tex | open main.pdf` works perfectly fine in my computer :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this for a start:

```bsh
complatex () 
{ 
    if [[ -n $1 ]]; then
        pdflatex -output-directory $(dirname "$1") "$1" &&
        xdg-open "${1%%.tex}.pdf"
    else
        for i in *.tex; do
            if [[ ! -f ${i%%.tex}.pdf ]]; then
                pdflatex "$i" &&
                xdg-open "${i%%.tex}.pdf"
            fi
        done
    fi
}
```

Oneline version:

```bsh
complatex(){ if [[ $1 ]]; then pdflatex -output-directory $(dirname "$1") "$1" && xdg-open "${1%%.tex}.pdf"; else for i in *.tex; do if [[ ! -f ${i%%.tex}.pdf ]]; then pdflatex "$i" && xdg-open "${i%%.tex}.pdf"; fi; done; fi ;}
```

This function tests for an argument, if there is one it just runs `pdflatex` saving the output files in the argument's directory (instead of the current one) and opens the output `.pdf` in the default PDF viewer. If you call it without an argument, it goes through every `.tex` file in the current directory, tests whether there's a `.pdf` with the same name and only if not does the same as above.

To make the `complatex` command available on your system, just copy one of the two versions from above into either your `~/.bash_aliases` (create it if necessary) or your `~/.bashrc` file and open up a new terminal or source the changed file in an existing one with e.g. `source ~/.bash_aliases`.

#### Example run

```bsh
$ tree -A --noreport
.
├── dummy.pdf
├── dummy.tex
├── other\ dir
└── test.tex
$ complatex test.tex &>/dev/null  # opens test.pdf in PDF viewer
$ tree -A --noreport
.
├── dummy.pdf
├── dummy.tex
├── other\ dir
├── test.aux
├── test.log
├── test.pdf
└── test.tex
$ rm -f test.!(tex)  # removes the output files that were just created
$ cd other\ dir/
$ complatex ../test.tex &>/dev/null  # opens test.pdf in PDF viewer
$ ls  # other dir stays empty
$ cd ..
$ tree -A --noreport
.
├── dummy.pdf
├── dummy.tex
├── other\ dir
├── test.aux
├── test.log
├── test.pdf
└── test.tex
$ rm -f test.!(tex)  # removes the output files that were just created
$ complatex &>/dev/null  # opens test.pdf in PDF viewer, doesn't process dummy.tex as there's a dummy.pdf already
$ tree -A --noreport
.
├── dummy.pdf
├── dummy.tex
├── other\ dir
├── test.aux
├── test.log
├── test.pdf
└── test.tex
```