# How to restore my Firebird database and modify owner settings in a single command line?

Tags: command-line, permissions, database, ownership

I am using Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS and I've recently upgraded from Firebird 2.5 to Firebird 3.0.

Prior to upgrading, I was restoring my local database with the following unzip&replace command:

```
zcat /var/www/temp/<database name><backup timestamp>.gbak.gz | gbak -rep -v stdin /database/<database name>.fdb -user <username> -pass <password>
```

This did the whole job in one step and I dig that sort of thing. However, after upgrading Firebird I have discovered that FlameRobin (version 0.9.2.1850) will not connect to the updated database.  The error message (to help others who may be Googling) is:

> Engine Code: 335544344
> Engine Message: I/O error during "open" operation for file "/database/.fdb"
> Error while trying to open file
> Permission denied.

And my CodeIgniter project complains:

> Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.

To solve this, I change the `<database name>.fdb` file's owner and group to `firebird` and `firebird` then everything is sweet.  However I am doing this in two steps ...ugh, lame right? ...I know.

So I am wondering if I can execute something like [Change folder permissions and ownership](https://askubuntu.com/q/6723/955434) in the same line as my above unzip&replace command?

My system admin fu is not terribly impressive, so I haven't dared to get too crazy with my attempts, but I figure this should be a relatively basic task for those with experience in such things.

p.s. Ideally, I'd like it if I never had to change the owner settings on every restore, so if there is a way to do that -- that would be even better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After referring to

[Which one is better: using ; or && to execute multiple commands in one line?](https://askubuntu.com/a/539293/955434)

I added: `&& sudo chown firebird:firebird /database/<database name>.fdb` to my command to form:

```
zcat /var/www/temp/<database name><backup timestamp>.gbak.gz | gbak -rep -v stdin /database/<database name>.fdb -user <username> -pass <password> && sudo chown firebird:firebird /database/<database name>.fdb
```

This successfully changed the ownership settings in one line.

If there is a better practice I am happy to here it and why.