# need a single repository as argument

Tags: command-line, server, php7

Help need to fix this problem, Error: need a single repository as argument

I wrote this

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php sudo apt-get update
```

I am about to add php7 ppa:

Comment: Hello. Did you put this command all on one line and press enter at the end?  This is the command assuming the PPA info is correct. <sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php> minus the <> of course. Then on a separate line when that command finishes <sudo apt-get update>

Comment: Yeah, those are two separate commands. If you want to run them in one line, use `;` or `&&`: `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php; sudo apt-get update`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which one is better: using ; or && to execute multiple commands in one line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/334994/which-one-is-better-using-or-to-execute-multiple-commands-in-one-line)