# How to customize the font style in notify-send?

Tags: scripts, format, notify-send

I am trying to change the format of text appearing in pop-up notification while using `notify-send` command. [Here](https://askubuntu.com/a/548157/377375) I saw that it can be done using HTML formatting. But that doesn't seem to be working for me.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Notify-osd uses system font. Try patched version of notify-osd from leolik's ppa: https://launchpad.net/~leolik/+archive/ubuntu/leolik. And then you can modify various things: http://askubuntu.com/questions/128474/

Answer (score 13):

The issue might be that the `summary` string is not parsed, whereas the `body` string is parsed. The format should be **notify-send** <*OPTIONS summary body*>

You will notice in the code below the `summary` *(or title, or subject, one could say)* will not be formatted, but the `body` string will be.

*You can pass an empty string for the summary, but the spacing will still be there. Although the title is optional, it's suggested to include it in the event your notifications are used in other applications such as tickers or feeds that do not require or support anything but plain text.*

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
phrase="Hey sexy, it's `date +'%l:%M %P'`"
/usr/bin/notify-send --icon=clock -t 4000 "<i>Time Now</i>" "<span color='#57dafd' font='26px'><i><b>$phrase</b></i></span>" >/dev/null 2>&1
```

according to the docs the `summary` is:

> a single line overview of the notification. For instance, "You have
>   mail" or "A friend has come online". It should generally not be longer
>   than 40 characters, though this is not a requirement, and server
>   implementations should word wrap if necessary. The summary must be
>   encoded using UTF-8."

For more info on styling the body text, see http://www.galago-project.org/specs/notification/0.9/x161.html

Comment: I have to add `--urgency=critical` to make it work on my machine (probably because youtube is running on another screen).

Comment: Good call. If you plan on using in a cron job you'll likely need to add **DISPLAY=:0.0** at the top of your crontab. Some apps and services that require your display manager's config, such as notify-send, will not work properly without this. **aws-cli** will likely require **HOME=/home/me** as well, if you plan on text-to-speeching with Polly, which I highly recommend!